# React Router - Prevent fallthrough?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I figure this is likely pretty straightforward.

I have the following routes defined:

```
<SecureRoute path='/test/:name' component={SpecificTest} />
<SecureRoute path='/test' component={TestList} />
```

I want to route to different components based on wether or not a parameter has been supplied to :name. The routing above produces a view with BOTH `SpecificTest` and `TestList` components. How can I stop the route processing after the first is hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will get that with [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md):

```
<Switch>
  <SecureRoute path='/test/:name' component={SpecificTest} />
  <SecureRoute path='/test' component={TestList} />
</Switch>
```

Its role is to render first matched route.

Answer (score 0):

In React Router 4 the [Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md) component will only render the first matching component. In which case order will also matter. You may also want to use the [exact](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool) boolean parameter for your base route.

```
<Switch>
    <SecureRoute exact path='/test' component={TestList} />
    <SecureRoute path='/test/:name' component={SpecificTest} />
</Switch>
```